# MacBook Pro doesn’t boot

Tags: macos, windows

I followed [this tutorial](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384447/40457) to install Windows 10 on external drive.

I followed it until step 7, then I quit and restart the MacBook but now it doesn’t boot in macOS. I disconnected the external drive and restored the original boot settings. When I turn it on, it keeps restarting on its own after displaying the Apple logo and making the sound.

What can I do? Any advice is welcome. In the worst case, I'm asking for advice on how to recover data from the internal hard drive and then reinstall macOS.

Comment: Related question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411597/how-to-recover-specific-items-when-macbookpro-wont-boot?rq=1).

Comment: How did you restore the original boot settings? Can you boot the Mac to Internet Recovery?